# Xnet получить исх код из функции c#

Tags: c#, xnet

Т.к мне часто приходится делать гет запросы я вывел все в отдельную функцию

```
HttpResponse GET(string url, string useragent, CookieDictionary cookies, string proxx)
{
    try
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequest())
        {

            if (proxx != "")
                request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(proxx);
            request.Cookies = cookies; request.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
            request.UserAgent = useragent;
            request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            var txtresult = request.Get(url);
            return txtresult;
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
var txtresult = GET("https://whoer.net/ru", "", null, proxx).ToString();
```

В результате получаю ошибку `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.`. Такая же ошибка, если принять `httpresponse`, а потом вытащить исх код

```
 var result = GET("https://whoer.net/ru", "", null, proxx);
 txtresult = result.ToString();
```

Хотя кукисы  и тп получаю без проблем.

Если в самой функции остановить и проверить, что выдает `var rrr = txtresult.ToString();` , то туда записывается исх код страницы. Куда он девается, когда я получаю результат ?

Comment: А в какой конкретно строке вылетает? Какая конкретно переменная равна `null` в момент обращения?

Comment: @VladD на строке, где присутствует `.ToString() `. Я привел 2 примера вызова: 
1. `var txtresult = GET("https://whoer.net/ru", "", null, proxx).ToString(); `- вылетает ошибка тут
2. `txtresult = result.ToString(); `- вылатает ошибка тут

При этом в самой функции проверяю результат `.ToString();` - и дает все верно

Comment: @VladD "Какая конкретно переменная равна null в момент обращения?" - если я вас правильно понял, то ни одна.

Comment: @Lolidze: Ну у вас внутри функции происходит исключение, и вы его подавили возвратом `null`. Берите отладчик и выясняйте, что за исключение у вас.

Comment: @VladD так нет, исключение не возникает в самой функции. Это, видимо, баг у библиотеки xNet. Заметил : если я в функции перед return присвою какой-то переменной значение .ToString() , тобишь исх код, то в результате от функции я не получу ошибку, а просто пустую строку, иначе же будет ошибка

Comment: @Lolidze: Если исключение не возникает в функции, попробуйте убрать try/catch на время. И выясните в отладчике, какое в точности выражение равно `null`. При необходимости введите дополнительные переменные.

Comment: @VladD  `var result = GET("https://whoer.net/ru", "", null, proxx); // переменная не равна null, да и в событиях не вижу ошибки + отладчиком останавливал в функции на return, все нормально
                txtresult = result.ToString(); // а вот тут уже ошибка`

Comment: @Lolidze: Чудеса какие-то, так не бывает. Да, а txtresult — это локальная переменная, поле или свойство?

Comment: @VladD у меня много случаев магии с .ToString(); в библиотеке xNET. txtresult - это локальная переменная, ее я объявляю выше, как стринг. Если хотите, я по тимвиверу все покажу

Comment: @Lolidze: Я с телефона, у меня не выйдет.

Comment: @Lolidze: Раз магия, то поймайте исключение (nullreferenceexception) и дайте его StackTrace.

Comment: @VladD где мне его ловить ? ведь в функции тот же самый .tostring() не дает ошибки, он возвращает исх код. Я проверял вплоть до return , все было норм. Я, конечно, могу извратиться и возвращать 2 значения через tuple, ведь в функции у меня tostring() не вызывает ошибки, но хотелось бы более цивильно и удобнее. Не понимаю, почему выходит ошибка

Comment: @Lolidze: Ловите там, где вы его получаете. И проверьте переменную на null перед обращением на всякий случай.

Comment: Кратко: у вас ошибка в строчке **`return null;`**

Comment: @PavelMayorov разве ? я убрал `try catch` и соответственно `return null;` , но ошибка при получении исх кода `.tostring()` осталась при этом куки, хэдеры и тп получаю  хорошо

Comment: @Lolidze а почему вы не исправили свой вопрос?

Comment: @PavelMayorov всм ? дело же не в `try catch` и возвращаемом `return null`; было. Я вообще хз в чем дело, я сделал так : записал в переменную исх код страницы (в самой функции) и возвращаю через tuple 2 значения.